# add an event to fullCalendar using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm trying to add an event to a calendar using the famous fullCalendar of Adam Shaw. I have a form where a user can enter the properties of the event he wants to create. 
I'm new to jquery, so I began with a static add of an event. Here is what I have just after the form :

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="add_event();">Save</a> &nbsp; <a class="btn" href="#">Cancel</a>
    function add_event()
        {  document.write('ajax call');
              $.ajax({   
                    type : 'POST',  
                    url: '<?php echo site_url()."/public/calendar/addEvent" ?>',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: 'true',
                    success: function(data)

                    {   document.write('je commence');
                                    var event = {
                              title : "AJAX",
                              start : "2012-08-16",
                              end   : "2012-08-17"
                                  };

                               $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', event, true )

                                            }               
                         else
                        {   document.write('else');
                            // Display error
                        }  
                }


            }); 

        }
```

just the "begin" is printed.
Could anyone tell me how can I correct this please.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In fullcalendar "select" option is used to create a event in particular dates http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/select_callback/

Check this link
http://jsfiddle.net/xSYj9/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really understand what do you mean. Actually, I managed to add the event when I did it separately in another file (without ajax call) using $(document).ready(function() { ----- I'm new to Ajax and I think the problem is with the ajax call . Maybe could you help me ...